# APR calculation formula

Tags: algorithm, math

I posted this in banking stackexchange too, but since it is more of an algorithm, I figured someone here would be able to answer my question

I am using the formula listed on this site:

http://www.fdic.gov/regulations/laws/rules/6500-1950.html#fdic6500appendixjtopart226

(go to appendix J, if it doesn't auto scroll).

In step 9, they are trying to find the value of A = (33.61 * )/ (i+1)

and that is calculated as 1 + 1/(i+1) + 1/(i+1)^2 +......1/(i+1)^n

Taking n = 36, I find = 28.83,

and I am getting the value of A = 33.61 * 28.83 / 1.0104 = 941.3

But, the link somehow arrives at the number of 1004.674391

Can anyone explain how they arrive at this number and what A' and A'' mean?

I am trying to code for this in C++, but before I do, I need to get the math straight on pencil.

Comment: voting to close - this isn't really programming-related, but math related. try asking at [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com): "This is a free, community driven Q&A for people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No wonder US economy is heading in the direction of that of Greece.

Lord, if people at the FDIC are using Linear interpolation to find interest rates then no wonder home owners can't afford to pay back their loans

Linear interpolation requires knowing two rates one at which the present value of the annuity is higher than the present value at the actual rate and another rate at which present value is lower than the present value at the actual rate

Once you have the two rates, the two present values then you can use the linear interpolation formula to approximate the actual rate

But then how would you know the two rates at which present value is at odds with the actual rate. Keep on guessing if you have time to kill

Any way to answer to your question about why your A' differs from that shown on the FDIC document, see the following two calculations of A' and A'' at interest rate of 12.5% and 12.6% respectively

```
[Present Value Annuity Due][1] = 33.61 x (1 + 0.010416667) x { 1 - 1/(1 + 0.010416667)^36 }/0.010416667
= 33.61 x 1.010416667 x { 1 - 1/(1.010416667)^36 }/0.010416667
= 33.61 x 1.010416667 x { 1 - 1/1.45217196873 }/0.010416667
= 33.61 x 1.010416667 x { 1 - 0.688623676487 }/0.010416667
= 33.61 x 1.010416667 x { 0.311376323513/0.010416667 }
= 33.61 x 1.010416667 x 29.8921261007
= 33.61 x 30.2035024242
PVAD = 1015.14

A' = PVAD / (1+i)
A' = 1015.14 / 1.010416667
A' = $1,004.67

Present Value Annuity Due = 33.61 x (1 + 0.0105) x { 1 - 1/(1 + 0.0105)^36 }/0.0105
= 33.61 x 1.0105 x { 1 - 1/(1.0105)^36 }/0.0105
= 33.61 x 1.0105 x { 1 - 1/1.45648978356 }/0.0105
= 33.61 x 1.0105 x { 1 - 0.68658222755 }/0.0105
= 33.61 x 1.0105 x { 0.31341777245/0.0105 }
= 33.61 x 1.0105 x 29.8493116619
= 33.61 x 30.1627294344
PVAD = 1013.77

A'' = PVAD / (1+i)
A'' = 1013.77 / 1.0105
A'' = $1,003.23
```

If you have to program this in code, I suggest you find time to read on material related to numerical methods. Mind you, this too is a guessing game but much more elegant than linear interpolation

The formula listed on that FDIC page is about finding present value of an ordinary annuity that makes periodic end of period payments. The rate you will get for the example will be a monthly rate that you have to multiply with 12 to get the annual rate. There is also something called an annualized rate which is found by (1+i)^12 - 1

The example states of finding an annual rate for a loan amount of $1,000 for which a monthly payment of $33.61 is due at the end of each of the next 36 months

I will show you a method called Newton Raphson technique of finding interest rate for an annuity that makes uniform series of payments

There are two different equations that you can use. The first one is used to find future value of an annuity and the second one is used to find present value of an annuity

Excel uses the future value equation to solve for its 5 TVM functions and TI BA II plus uses present value equation to solve for its 5 TVM functions

If you have any questions, you can leave me a message on the site in reference. Good luck in coding. You might find learning a bit about Pre-Calculus especially the stuff about derivatives

The periodic or monthly rate for this loan is 0.010687973564 meaning 1.07%

And the annual rate would be 0.010687973564 x 12 = 0.128255682768 or 12.83%

```
Newton Raphson Method IRR Calculation with TVM equation = 0

TVM Eq. 1: PV(1+i)^N + PMT(1+i*type)[(1+i)^N -1]/i + FV = 0

f(i) = 0 + 33.61 * (1 + i * 0) [(1+i)^36 - 1)]/i + -1000 * (1+i)^36

f'(i) = (33.61 * ( 36 * i * (1 + i)^(35+0) - (1 + i)^36) + 1) / (i * i)) + 36 * -1000 * (1+0.1)^35

i0 = 0.1
f(i1) = -20859.0286
f'(i1) = -772196.0009
i1 = 0.1 - -20859.0286/-772196.0009 = 0.0729873910496
Error Bound = 0.0729873910496 - 0.1 = 0.027013 > 0.000001

i1 = 0.0729873910496
f(i2) = -7274.5413
f'(i2) = -301995.7711
i2 = 0.0729873910496 - -7274.5413/-301995.7711 = 0.0488991687999
Error Bound = 0.0488991687999 - 0.0729873910496 = 0.024088 > 0.000001

i2 = 0.0488991687999
f(i3) = -2431.1344
f'(i3) = -124187.6435
i3 = 0.0488991687999 - -2431.1344/-124187.6435 = 0.0293228701788
Error Bound = 0.0293228701788 - 0.0488991687999 = 0.019576 > 0.000001

i3 = 0.0293228701788
f(i4) = -732.3776
f'(i4) = -57078.0048
i4 = 0.0293228701788 - -732.3776/-57078.0048 = 0.0164917006907
Error Bound = 0.0164917006907 - 0.0293228701788 = 0.012831 > 0.000001

i4 = 0.0164917006907
f(i5) = -167.5999
f'(i5) = -32858.4347
i5 = 0.0164917006907 - -167.5999/-32858.4347 = 0.0113910349433
Error Bound = 0.0113910349433 - 0.0164917006907 = 0.005101 > 0.000001

i5 = 0.0113910349433
f(i6) = -17.997
f'(i6) = -26021.5726
i6 = 0.0113910349433 - -17.997/-26021.5726 = 0.010699415611
Error Bound = 0.010699415611 - 0.0113910349433 = 0.000692 > 0.000001

i6 = 0.010699415611
f(i7) = -0.288
f'(i7) = -25192.367
i7 = 0.010699415611 - -0.288/-25192.367 = 0.0106879831887
Error Bound = 0.0106879831887 - 0.010699415611 = 1.1E-5 > 0.000001

i7 = 0.0106879831887
f(i8) = -0.0001
f'(i8) = -25178.8435
i8 = 0.0106879831887 - -0.0001/-25178.8435 = 0.0106879801183
Error Bound = 0.0106879801183 - 0.0106879831887 = 0 < 0.000001

IRR = 1.07%


Newton Raphson Method IRR Calculation with TVM equation = 0

TVM Eq. 2: PV + PMT(1+i*type)[1-{(1+i)^-N}]/i + FV(1+i)^-N = 0

f(i) = -1000 + 33.61 * (1 + i * 0) [1 - (1+i)^-36)]/i + 0 * (1+i)^-36

f'(i) = (-33.61 * (1+i)^-36 * ((1+i)^36 - 36 * i - 1) /(i*i)) + (0 * -36 * (1+i)^(-36-1))

i0 = 0.1
f(i1) = -674.7726
f'(i1) = -2860.8622
i1 = 0.1 - -674.7726/-2860.8622 = -0.135863356364
Error Bound = -0.135863356364 - 0.1 = 0.235863 > 0.000001

i1 = -0.135863356364
f(i2) = 46220.4067
f'(i2) = -1361282.2783
i2 = -0.135863356364 - 46220.4067/-1361282.2783 = -0.101909776386
Error Bound = -0.101909776386 - -0.135863356364 = 0.033954 > 0.000001

i2 = -0.101909776386
f(i3) = 14472.9891
f'(i3) = -417070.1913
i3 = -0.101909776386 - 14472.9891/-417070.1913 = -0.0672082095036
Error Bound = -0.0672082095036 - -0.101909776386 = 0.034702 > 0.000001

i3 = -0.0672082095036
f(i4) = 4620.5467
f'(i4) = -136713.9676
i4 = -0.0672082095036 - 4620.5467/-136713.9676 = -0.0334110286059
Error Bound = -0.0334110286059 - -0.0672082095036 = 0.033797 > 0.000001

i4 = -0.0334110286059
f(i5) = 1412.836
f'(i5) = -50859.7324
i5 = -0.0334110286059 - 1412.836/-50859.7324 = -0.00563196002357
Error Bound = -0.00563196002357 - -0.0334110286059 = 0.027779 > 0.000001

i5 = -0.00563196002357
f(i6) = 345.5376
f'(i6) = -24366.4494
i6 = -0.00563196002357 - 345.5376/-24366.4494 = 0.00854891782087
Error Bound = 0.00854891782087 - -0.00563196002357 = 0.014181 > 0.000001

i6 = 0.00854891782087
f(i7) = 37.705
f'(i7) = -17208.0395
i7 = 0.00854891782087 - 37.705/-17208.0395 = 0.010740042325
Error Bound = 0.010740042325 - 0.00854891782087 = 0.002191 > 0.000001

i7 = 0.010740042325
f(i8) = -0.8934
f'(i8) = -16335.3764
i8 = 0.010740042325 - -0.8934/-16335.3764 = 0.0106853483863
Error Bound = 0.0106853483863 - 0.010740042325 = 5.5E-5 > 0.000001

i8 = 0.0106853483863
f(i9) = 0.0452
f'(i9) = -16356.5205
i9 = 0.0106853483863 - 0.0452/-16356.5205 = 0.0106881114105
Error Bound = 0.0106881114105 - 0.0106853483863 = 3.0E-6 > 0.000001

i9 = 0.0106881114105
f(i10) = -0.0023
f'(i10) = -16355.4516
i10 = 0.0106881114105 - -0.0023/-16355.4516 = 0.010687973564
Error Bound = 0.010687973564 - 0.0106881114105 = 0 < 0.000001

IRR = 1.07%
```

References

[Internal rate of return IRR](http://finance.thinkanddone.com/irr.html)

TVM Equation to find IRR with [Newton Raphson method](http://finance.thinkanddone.com/finding_irr_with_tvm_equation_using_newton_raphson_method.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand where you get 28.83 from.

```
sum(1/(1+.0104)**i for i in xrange(36)) == 30.2116668761916
```

Also, carry more digits for `i`.  You're using i=.0104, but they're using i=.010416667.